What are the procedures when a Muslim man is marrying a Christian woman in a Islamic marriage?
Can a christian man give his daughter away in a muslim marriage?

Please perform basic research on your own and ask a useful question.

The procedure is the same as that for marrying a muslim woman.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].
